# React Child Component Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a parent class that holds two child components, with one of the children trying to pass data back to the parent's state. When I run the code, I do not get any runtime errors, but the child that is sending data back to the parent is not rendering at all (even initially). All the components are capitalized so that is not the issue. I think it has something to do with the syntax in the OnClick function, or my method of passing the props back to the parent. I am new to React, so any help would be appreciated!

**Parent Class**

```
  class DropdownParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {propsForClassDropdown: []};
    this.getClasses = this.getClasses.bind(this);
  }

  getClasses(subjectTitle){
    var chosenSubject = Subjects.subjectTitle;
    this.setState({propsForClassDropdown: {chosenSubject}.classes})
  }


  render(){
    return(
    <div className = "DropdownContainer">
      <SubjectDropdown triggerListChange = {this.getClasses} />
      <ClassDropdown />     //this one renders properly
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child component that is not rendering**

```
class SubjectDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchTerm: "", searchStarted: false };
    this.searchUpdated = this.searchUpdated.bind(this);
  }
  searchUpdated (term) {
    this.setState({searchTerm: term, searchStarted: true})
  }

  render(){
    console.log("rendering");
    const filteredSubjects = Subjects.filter(createFilter(this.state.searchTerm, KEYS_TO_FILTERS))
    return(
    <div>
      <div className = "SubjectDropdownContainer">
        <SearchInput className='search-input' onChange={this.searchUpdated} />
            <div className = 'SubjectDropdown'>
              {filteredSubjects.map(Subjects => {
                  return (
                    <div>
                    <Button className = "dropdownItem" key={Subjects.id} onClick={()=>this.props.triggerListChange(key)}>
                      {Subjects.subject.name}
                    </Button>
                    </div>
                  )
              })}
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: please show how you export and import the child component. :)

Comment: Are you getting any error? Is `console.log("rendering");` being reached?

Comment: the console.log("rendering") is never reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onClick` handler, you pass `key` to triggerListChange but `key` isn't defined anywhere.

```
{filteredSubjects.map(Subjects => {
              return (
                <div>
                <Button className = "dropdownItem" key={Subjects.id} onClick={()=>this.props.triggerListChange()}>
                  {Subjects.subject.name}
                </Button>
                </div>
              )
          })}
```

Assuming `Subjects` is within scope of the parent and child component, and `Subject` is an object, that should work.

In the callback to your map function: `filteredSubjects.map(Subjects => {` the name of the `Subject`s parameter collides with your global Subjects object. Try changing that to: `filteredSubjects.map(subject=> {` and pass subject.id to `triggerListChange`. Ie; `onClick={() => this.props.triggerListChange(subject.id)`

In your getClasses function:

```
getClasses(subjectTitle){
  var chosenSubject = Subjects.subjectTitle;
  this.setState({propsForClassDropdown: {chosenSubject}.classes})
}
```

Change `var chosenSubject = Subjects.subjectTitle` to accessing the property via bracket `[]` notation: `Subjects[subjectTitle]` because the `id` from your subject object might be a string.

Comment: say I wanted to pass the value of key (which is equal to {Subjects.id}) as a parameter to the trigger function. How would I do this? I tried to pass {Subjects.id} as an argument, but it didn't work.

Comment: Declaring an arrow function in a jsx property is not optimal because that arrow function would be created every time the component is re-rendered. I didn't want to point this out in my answer because you're just starting out with react and you can optimize as you do more research. In the callback to your map: `filteredSubjects.map(Subjects => {` `Subjects` the name of the `Subjects` parameter collides with your global Subjects object. Try changing that to:  `filteredSubjects.map(subject=> {` and pass `subject.id` and pass to triggerListChange. Editing answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my export statement in the parent component was incorrect. Not sure why one of the components was still rendering though.